# Busted encoding in XLSX document - what encoding is this?

Tags: excel, text, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I was given an XLSX document that had been worked on by another user, and from casual inspection it looks like the encoding is totally busted.  I used Excel 2011 to open the XLSX file and saved the document as a Windows CSV file so I could run a script through it and figure out what encoding it was.  However, doing this, I have only found myself even more confused.

The ASCII range at 0-127 all seems to be correct and readable.  I then wrote a script to parse the entire CSV file and only output cells that had bytes `80` through `ff`.  By looking at various cells and filling in the blanks, I believe i have found the following translations - they may not all be 100% accurate:

- `e5 ca` => *blank*
- `cc 5f` => ä as in Bättner
- `cc a4` => ç as in Jean-François
- `cc a6` => ö as in Hölzlestr
- `cc a8` => î as in Jean-Benoît
- `cc a9` => é as in Dupré
- `cc ac` => è as in Hélène
- `cc b1` => ñ as in Muñoz
- `cc c1` => á as in Mullá and Chávez
- `cc d9` => ß as in Auerstraße
- `cc e4` => É as in Émile

In addition, the prefix `cc c4 e5` appears several times in the data, and seems to map to the same thing as `cc` - for example, `cc c4 e5 c1` appears to map to the same character (á) as `cc c1`.

It occurred to me that this might not even all be the same encoding - this XLSX document was based on data that was contained in an online mailing list, and different sources of data for the mailing list might have had different encoding...issues.

**EDIT** So one of the solutions got it right on the money that many of these fields seemed to be UTF-8 interpreted as Windows-1252 encoded as MacRoman.  I was able to reverse MacRoman to Windows-1252 and got valid UTF-8 byte sequences.  However, this does not cover all of the cases...it does not explain the `cc c4 e5` sequence, and one of the encodings in the table above I had presumed was off-base - `cc 5f` does not turn into ä when reversed.  However, I have discovered that there are actually several encodings like `cc 5f` that I think might have a clue or two.  Here are two bytestrings that my previous strategy could not decode...

`4a 65 74 74 cc c4 e5 f8 cc e2 e5 c0 cc e2 e5 5f`

`48 cc 5f e5 5f e5 5f cc 5f e5 a6 e5 a8 65 72`

That `5f` is coming up an awful lot...

Comment: If there were different encoding issues they would show up in the source. You cannot have two different encodings in a single document. Check the source first. [edit] Perhaps you could post a link to a public share on a redacted copy of that file.

Comment: You cannot have two different encodings for a single document, but you can have data with different incorrect encodings - the file might be ISO8859-1, but you could have incorrectly-encoded UTF-8 data on one line and incorrectly-encoded...say... Shift JIS data in another.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of those look like Macs may have been involved at some point, and the path was something like utf-8 -> cp125(2/4) -> mac_roman.

```
>>> for char in chars[1:]:
    print(char, hexlify(char.encode("utf-8").decode("cp1252").encode("mac_roman")))
...     
ç b'cca4'
ö b'cca6'
î b'cca8'
é b'cca9'
è b'ccac'
ñ b'ccb1'
á b'ccc1'
ß b'ccd9'
É b'cce4'
```

This can't explain `ä`, but I do think it confirms that most of your assignments are probably right.

Comment: This actually makes a little sense.  The source of this data claims to encode it as UTF-8, but maybe when the export to from the source to XLSX was done, Excel treated it as Windows-1252.  I then opened the Excel document and subsequently exported it as CSV, which according to various other sources on the web claims that Excel does this in MacRoman.

Comment: This reverse encoding actually was pretty good, it gave me several other letters that I had not been able to infer.  However, my suspicion that there were other incorrect encodings was right on, as there are several other fields that don't decode properly.  The cc c4 e5 bytes in particular don't appear to decode.